# Why is new Date() removing a day? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am creating a date with `new Date()`.  When I do this, it is subtracting a day.  Here is the code:

```
var dateString = "2016-04-10";
var date = new Date(dateString);

// date = Sat Apr 09 2016 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT)
```

What do I misunderstand?  Why is the date not `Apr 10 2016`?  How do I make this work properly?

Comment: try `new Date(2016,4,10);`

Comment: Uh, the date you have there *is* midnight (0:00) of Apr 10 2016?

Comment: I am receiving the date formatted in the above manner.  I need to make that format work?  Is there a way to make that happen?

Comment: @jhamm: The date object you have is correct. It's just your output format that is timezone-dependent - use `.toUTCString()` instead of `.toString()`

Comment: This question has been asked many, many times before. The [*TC39 committee*](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/87) apparently thought treating ISO 8601 format dates as UTC when the standard treats them as local would avoid confusion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your timezone is GMT-6 (as revealed by the `GMT-0600 (MDT)` in the output you've provided). Therefore the date which gets generated is offset by -6 hours. In this case, midnight minus 6 hours is 6PM on the previous day.

If you call `date.toISOString()`, you'll see that the UTC time is `"2016-04-10T00:00:00.000Z"` as expected.

Comment: "As expected" only if you are aware of the inconsistencies of ECMAScript 2015 date string parsing.