# AngularUI Datepicker disable dates outside of range

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datepicker, angularjs-controller

I want to limit the Angular UI Datepicker to be between two dates passed in as variables. Preferably I'd like to get it working without adding a library like momentjs, because this is the only field in which I need to work with dates.

Here is a plunker of this problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/zsjpoVZtHqJLIP2RW6vm?p=preview

here are the variables:

```
mycurrentdate = '2016-04-18'
mymindate = '2016-04-01'
mymaxmonth = '2016-05-01'
mymaxdate will be calculated from mymaxmonth to be
mymaxdate = '2016-05-31'
```

My actual max date will be the the last day of mymaxmonth

```
$scope.maxDate = new Date(
                    $scope.mymaxmonth + (TO THE END OF THE MONTH)
                );
```

One thing to note is that running it through `new Date()` returns a date that is the day before the given date. For example:

```
$scope.minDate = new Date(
                    $scope.mymindate
                );
```

$scope.minDate returns `Wed Mar 30 2016 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)` I looked up the reason for why it returns March 30 instead of April 1st and it seems like a timezone error?

I want to set a mymindate of '2016-04-01' and get mymaxdate = '2016-05-31' and disable all dates outside of this range. I've read [Beginners Guide to Javascript Date and Time](http://www.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-to-javascript-date-and-time/) and tried it out here.

In the controller I have:

```
$scope.mymindate = '2016-04-01';
$scope.mymaxmonth = '2016-05-01'; //want mymaxdate to be '2016-05-31'

 $scope.minDate = new Date($scope.dt.getFullYear(), $scope.dt.getMonth(), 1);

 $scope.maxDate = new Date($scope.dt.getFullYear(), $scope.dt.getMonth() + 1, 0);
```

In the template I have:

```
    <p class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
      </span>
    </p>
```

Comment: "*… seems like a timezone error*". Not an error, a poor design decision by the authors of ECMA-262, see [*Why is new Date() removing a day?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698286/why-is-new-date-removing-a-day-javascript). The only way to avoid the poor parsing of the *Date* constructor (and *Date.parse*, they are equivalent) is to manually parse the date. So either write a function (2 lines of code) or use a library. There are many small parsing and formatting libraries on GitHub, or go for moment.js if you have other date things to do as well.

Comment: Oh, note that if you have a Date for 31-May-2016 and add one month you'll get 01-July-2016 (since there is no 31 June, it rolls over to July). Date arithmetic isn't trivial and why most use a small (or maybe large) library for such things.

Comment: @RobG This is the only time in my application i'll be using dates so I'd prefer to stay away from adding a library dependency if possible.

Comment: In that case you should use an *addMonths* function that checks the initial date vs the final date. If they're different it means adding a month rolled over an extra month (e.g. initial 31, final 1), so set the date to  zero so it's the last day of the previous month (so 31 May + 1 Month -> 31 June -> 1 July -> set to 0 July -> 30 June. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some annoying date manipulations, I got it. 
Here is the working plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/6U4YdTIyFXjOqRJm2qTq?p=preview

In my controller I have:

```
var mindate = new Date($scope.mymindate);
$scope.minDate = new Date(mindate.getTime()+(1*24*60*60*1000)); //Due to poor design by the authors of ECMA-262 the date is parsed to be a day behind, so we must add a day

var maxdate = new Date($scope.mymaxmonth);
$scope.maxDate = new Date(maxdate.getFullYear(), maxdate.getMonth() + 2, 0); //Add a month to get to the end of the month.

$scope.dateOptions = {
    maxDate: $scope.maxDate,
    minDate: $scope.minDate,
};
```

In my template:

```
datepicker-options="dateOptions"
```

I didn't end up needing min-date or max-date because dateoptions covers both. I'll be honest, not sure why you have to add two to the macdate.getMonth() instead of just one, but it worked out.

Comment: according to your question `maxdate='2016-05-01'` and wanted disable after `2016-05-31` so if you add `maxdate.getMonth() + 2` then fulfill your requirement? your demo shown disable after 2 month

Answer (score 5):

you need to set  `datepicker-options` with proper `option` for your `input` to disable date. In your example used `datepicker-options="dateOptions"` but in your controller didn't declare `dateOptions`.

So you need to set `dateOptions` for `maxDate` and `minDate`. like

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
    maxDate: new Date($scope.maxDate),
    minDate: new Date($scope.mymindate)
};
```

and set `maxDate` and `minDate` like:

```
$scope.mymindate = new Date('2016-04-01');
$scope.mymaxmonth = new Date('2016-05-01'); //wanted mymaxdate to be '2016-05-31'

$scope.minDate = new Date($scope.mymindate);

$scope.maxDate = new Date($scope.mymaxmonth.getFullYear(),$scope.mymaxmonth.getMonth()+1,0);
```

and HTML:

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input  type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" min="minDate" max="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
</p>
```

Can see [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Enwjx0s3wOrVTqoZkXsu?p=preview) and hopefully it will help you :)