# moment.js offset by one day issue

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

Some of my users report different outputs, offset by one day.

Code:

```
var call=[1451084400000,1451170800000,1451257200000,1451343600000,1451430000000,1451516400000,1451602800000,1451689200000,1451775600000]

    var arrayLength = call.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += moment(call[i],"x").format("YYYY-MM-DD")+"<br>"
    }
```

Expected result:

```
2015-12-26
2015-12-27
2015-12-28
2015-12-29
2015-12-30
2015-12-31
2016-01-01
2016-01-02
2016-01-03
```

Issue:

```
2015-12-25
2015-12-26
2015-12-27
2015-12-28
2015-12-29
2015-12-30
2015-12-31
2016-01-01
2016-01-02
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: More than likely related to timezone offsets.  If you can log the actual millisecond count, you would more than likely see that the values are the same, you are just hitting day boundaries based on timezone.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate (it doesn't use moment.js) but it's the same issue: [*Why is new Date() removing a day?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698286/why-is-new-date-removing-a-day-javascript).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165182/strange-behavior-formatting-moment-js-date/36168554#36168554. This is a moment specific question/answer. Basically, you want moment.utc()

Comment: @MaggiePint ok now when I use the parseZone I get the same issue my users see. But...the correct date is without the parseZone :)

Comment: It sounds like you want the date to display in your time zone, even if the user is in a different time zone. You will need moment timezone for that.

Comment: Why don't you just pass a string? A time value represents an instant in time, so what the user sees will depend on the time zone setting of their host. If you just want to represent a date without regard for time zone, just send a string.

Comment: @RobG I pass this as integers as I need to do some sorting first.

Comment: @RobG is correct in that, if you have a string, that's going to be way easier than moment timezone. Just make the string in ISO8601 format. That format sorts just fine in lexicographical order.

Comment: ok I have tried saving dates with .utc and .parseZone but this till occurs when I try to show the dates using .utc .parseZone  (now all the dates are -1 day...)

Comment: ok so assuming I get all the dates as integers via API, all set as unix timestamp I'd like to show them always in UTC. When I use .utc I get -1 day. that's the issue now

Comment: What you are seeing is the correct date, you're assuming the wrong date. A time value of `1451084400000` is 2015-12-25T23:00:00.000Z, which is GMT. Change the time zone to 1 hour east or more and the date changes.

Comment: @RobG strings helped. This should be the answer posted by you

Comment: @MaggiePint your link helped a lot!

Comment: @RobG how do I mark your answer as answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert to the desired timezone. For London timezone should be like this:

```
date.clone().tz("Europe/London");
```

Comment: 1. I'd like this to be universal
2. users are in the tz +3/+2 hrs, not whole day

Comment: Sometimes it adds a full day just because of a difference of few hours. Dont forget to define the timezone and you will never have problems.

Comment: ok, but adding tz for each date, and I have plenty of them, slows down the script a lot

Comment: so basically everything should be in the UTC

Comment: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3198580 . It could ease coding, but it would make it alot harder to compare relative times for the average human. It's up to us to adapt...